# Input validation in Android, Is declaring an InputType enough

Tags: android, validation, input

I have several fields in my activity which all take integers,  and integers only.
Looking around the SO here I see that the easiest way to perform validation is to simply declare an InputType of Integer in my layout.xml
This works fine.  User can only enter numbers and my business logic is happy. It can also handle blank fields.
However,  I was wondered is there any possible way a user can input a non numeric value?  Do I need to be able to handle this?  If the answer is yes then it means I will need to update all my unit tests along with the field validation in my application but would prefer to trust Android OS to do it.

Comment: what you want i mean  totally integer value without blank space?

Comment: I think you are covered. I can't imagine a way to input non numeric characters in the field. Even the copy paste function will not work if the copied text is alphabetical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use InputType correctly, the user won't be able to enter any characters that are not specified by that InputType.

Comment: Cheers,  looks like there's no need to be concerned about rouge characters then if I have an input type = Integer :)

Comment: You probably want to use "number" for the input type.

Answer (score 1):

if you're OC'ed about this, you can use InputFilter to prevent invalid characters from being entered/pasted into the EditText.

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequencefilter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for(int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if(!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```